# All forms and code vanished from Access database

Tags: ms-access

An Access database with a load of queries, tables, reports and forms with VBA code.

Was used in Access 2010 for ages, then some users upgraded to Office 2013 very recently.

One user had a "problem" on their computer while using the database, which may have resulted in their computer restarting, and now the database seems to have no forms or code visible when opened.

Googling finds reports of similar situations where the forms and code was there but invisible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to attempt is to open the database and choose `Compact and Repair`. I would then go into the VB Editor, if possible, and choose the Debug menu, Compile. While in the VB Editor, also check Tools, References for any missing references.

If the database is split to a back-end and front-end then just give them a new copy of the front-end. If this doesn't work then I would re-install Office on their computer.

If they have their own copy of the database (it is not split) then give them a new copy.

If they have already entered data that needs to be kept then I would start a new database and import all of the Access objects from the existing database. I have found that re-importing all objects solves most of these issues. You could import just the tables from their copy of the database, but the other objects from another copy.

If re-importing all objects doesn't resolve the issue then a remaining option is use the **decompile** command-line option:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE /decompile
```

Open Access from this command-line, go into the VB Editor and choose the Debug menu, Compile. Then close, re-open and Compact and Repair.

Comment: Thanks for very thorough answer. I've marked it as the answer but I can't actually test it any more.

Comment: Keep the answer for reference ;)

Comment: I shall, although I hope never to see Access again.